# Correct way to detect a new shape in a workbook after completing a paste operation

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

so i am currently doing this...

```
//Codeblock edited to include otaku upgrade
const String GIFpastespecialformat = @"Picture (GIF)";
const Int32 Onemoreshape = 1;
Int32 shapeCount = sht.Shapes.Count;
WorksheetPasteSpecialArgs wspa = new worksheetpastespecialargs();
wspa.Format = GIFpastespecialformat;
wspa.Link = False;
wspa.DisplayAsIcon = False;
List<Int32> oldShapes = new List<Int32>();
foreach (var item in sht.Shapes.Items())
{
   oldShapes.Add(Item.ID);
}
sht.PasteSpecial(wspa);
if((shapeCount + Onemoreshape) == sht.Shapes.Count)
{
  foreach (var item in sht.Shapes.Items())
  {
    if(oldShapes.Exists(i => i == item.ID) == false)
    {
      //work with shape here
    }
  }
}
else
{ 
   //report and deal with comexception, user intervention, etc
}
```

Where sht is the variable representing the worksheet i am working with.

Comment: Yeah, your code is probably as good as it gets. I wouldn't see many more ways that could be tweaked. If you're looking for a quicker/dirtier way, just do a `.Count` on the shapes and if your new count is more than before paste, then a Shape was inserted.

Comment: Thanks mate, post that as an answer and I will accept since it is coming from you :)

Comment: Done :) (oh wait, I have to type 15 characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is pretty solid. Probably the only enhancement I would make is just keep a count of the shapes - `oldShapes.Count` and just see if that number changes after a Paste. If so, a shape has been inserted.